# Add "open in terminal" shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys

I would like to create a Keyboard shortcut in order to open the terminal when browsing a given folder. I am using nautilus and Ubuntu 12.04.3

If we right click in a folder there is the option "Open in terminal".

I tried by adding in the  "System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcut" a new shortcut. As name I put "Open in Terminal" and as command for example I did "Ctrl+Super+t" but it does not work.

Comment: Check this answer (using dconf and F12): http://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here

Comment: I would like to create a shortcut by myself =)

Comment: 'Ctrl+Shift+T' should work just fine, without changing anything. As Sylvain Pineau suggested rightly, it would be easiest, to use dconf, to change the already existing shortcut to terminal.

Comment: 'Ctrl+Shift+T' does not open the terminal (maybe you wanted to say 'Ctrl+Alt+T'? But this open the terminal on the home folder). @DKBose, I don't understand your question, still at the first steps

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is Nautilus

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu

and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/69754/how-can-i-create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-my-nautilus-scripts

Comment: Probably what you are looking is answered here
http://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here)

Answer (score 11):

The best way I have found to do this without removing my hands from the keyboard:

Most keyboards nowadays have a "right click" key (don't know if it has an official name), located between the right alt and right ctrl, looks like an icon of a menu. Clicking on that opens up the right click menu of the current window (your mouse doesn't have to be in the window itself).

Therefore, the shortcut is **Keyboard Right Click Key + E**.

BTW, If you don't have a right click button on keyboard, you can right click using:
**SHIFT+F10**, and then press **E**. Less intuitive, but also works...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking for opening a folder that you are browsing in nautilus, in a terminal.

Just install nautilus open in terminal plugin by doing,

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

followed by restarting nautilus.

*Note that Ctrl+Alt+T will open the terminal always in your home folder path.*

Comment: No, I have already installed this. What I want is to create a shortcut that, while I am in a given folder, as for the 'Ctrl+Alt+T' shortcut, open the terminal in the folder I am browsing.