# How can I assign keyboard shortcut for nautilus scripts?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

I've setup a [Nautilus Script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto). I've put the script in `/home/sumeet/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` and it does appear in right click menu. and also works as expected. I just want to assign a shortcut to the script.

---

[How can I create keyboard shortcuts for my nautilus scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69754/how-can-i-create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-my-nautilus-scripts)

Answers given in the question above target a specific release and are completely outdated, and I couldn't find anything other than this question concerning this topic.

Comment: Can be done, but you need to edit the nautilus script a bit too. Is that possible in your case? (I suspect it is :) ). Bothe Serg and I did something like that here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/886642/how-can-i-set-a-shortcut-key-to-open-selected-file-in-nautilus. That solution can be applied here, but it takes the targeted script to receive the file or directory as argument.

Comment: @JacobVlijm it's the same script ([you know which one](https://askubuntu.com/a/918229/665251))

Comment: AHAAA, then the answer is quite simple. I hope I can post it somewhere today.

Comment: @JacobVlijm appreciate it man.

Comment: Hi Sumeet, I promiss I will apply the lost&found fix to all occurrences of the script, including the one I just posted. Immediately if I can breathe again :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'll need to test this first and then I'll accept the answer and I'll try to delay bounty as much as possible for better coverage, thanks again, I just can't test It right now, sorry about that :)

Comment: No problem at all! (of course)

Comment: Hi @SumeetDeshmukh, is anything wrong with the script? (I noticed you unaccepted)

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to reward bounty, but clicked on the accept sign, I'm on mobile

Comment: Haha, Yeah, I've been there :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How it can be done

When you right- click a file or folder for a nautilus script, the selected file is passed as an argument to the script. In most cases by something like:

```py
import os
subject = os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI")
```

...using python3, in its simplest form.

If you replace this by:

```py
import pyperclip

subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+c"])
subject = pyperclip.paste()
```

...the currently *selected* file is used inside the script as an argument

#### What you need

To use this solution (16.04 and up), you need to install both `xdotool`and `python3-pyperclip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyperclip xdotool
```

#### The complete script, mentioned in comments

then becomes:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import pyperclip

# --- set the list of valid extensions below (lowercase)
# --- use quotes, *don't* include the dot!
ext = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "icns", "ico"]
# --- set the list of preferred filenames
# --- use quotes
specs = ["folder.png", "cover.png", "monkey.png"]
# ---

# retrieve the path of the targeted folder
subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+c"])
dr = pyperclip.paste()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for directory in dirs:
        folder = os.path.join(root, directory)
        fls = os.listdir(folder)
        try:
            first = [p for p in fls if p in specs]
            first = first[0] if first else min(
                p for p in fls if p.split(".")[-1].lower() in ext
                )
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([
                "gvfs-set-attribute", "-t", "string",
                os.path.abspath(folder), "metadata::custom-icon",
                "file://"+os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, first))
                ])
```

Adding this to a shortcut key will set the icons for all directories *inside* the selected one.

#### Adding it to a shortcut key (!)

Adding shortcut keys, running (scripts using-) `xdotool` commands to press *another* key combination can be tricky. To prevent both key combinations to interfere with each other, use:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 1 && python3 /path/to/script.py"
```

#### Explanation

When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed while a file is selected, the *path* to the file is copied to the clipboard. We are simulating the key press with:

```
subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+c"])
```

`python`'s `pyperclip` module simply produces the path, stripped from `file://` when using `pyperclip.paste()` (this will not literally paste, but make the path available inside the script).

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to select files and execute actions it's possible to do it using just shell script with `xdotool` and `xclip`. So first install them:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool xclip
```

And then create the following script with the actions inside the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(mktemp)

xdotool key "Control_L+c"
variable="$( xclip -out -selection clipboard)"
variable="$( echo -e "$variable" | \
            awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n" } { printf "\"%s\" ", $1 }' | \
            sed -e s#\"\"## | \
            sed 's/" "/"\n"/g')"

echo "$variable" > $file

if [ -s "$file" ]; then
   while read absolute_path_file; do
      absolute_path_file="$(eval echo "$absolute_path_file")"
      base_name="$(basename "$absolute_path_file")"
      ### Execute the actions with the selected files here
      ### echo "$absolute_path_file"
      ### echo "$base_name"
   done < $file
fi
```

This script doesn't rely on the NAUTILUS variables and you can create a shortcut with it:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 1 && /path/script.bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using the procedure [outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/a/696901/558158), you can add a shortcut in Nautilus to a nautilus script. This works again as of Nautilus 40.
- Using `_` in the name of the nautilus script, you can assign a hotkey to a script. e.g, a script named "_Combine PDF" will show up with the C underlined. When a file is selected, you can quickly access the script with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>.

You can organize your scripts in subfolders. These subfolders also appear as menu choices, leading to a submenu. They also can be assigned a hotkey with this naming convention.