# If active window is file manager then store selected files in variable

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to port a script from AHK script for Windows to Python script for Ubuntu.

Desired behavior

(1) If user presses `F5` when active window is explorer it displays message "explorer is active". 
(2) If user presses `control-F6` when active window is explorer it displays message "Ctrl-F6 was pressed". 
(3) If user presses `F5` when active window is NOT explorer it displays a tooltip "Active app IS NOT explorer".
(4) If user presses `control-F6` when active window is NOT explorer nothing happens.

AHK implementation:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe explorer.exe    
F5::MsgBox % "explorer IS active"   /* scenario 1*/
^F6::MsgBox % "Ctrl-F6 was pressed"    /* scenario 2*/        
#if
F5::ToolTip % "Active app IS NOT explorer"      /* scenario 3*/
```

How to do this in Python under Ubuntu?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/918464/295286  It's basically Python approach that makes use of clipboard.

Comment: This sounds like a Windows question...

Comment: This is Ubuntu question. Simple script does this under Windows (see script below - it is working). But I can't adapt it for Linux...