# How can I create a shortcut to open a selected file with a particular Application?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde, pdf

I am trying to find a way to create a shortcut for opening a pdf file with a particular application. This is what i do currently(manually):

**Step 1**. I have a pdf file say MyBook.pdf. I right click on this pdf so that a popup window appears with many options like:

`Cut`

`Paste`

`Copy`

`Open with other application`

`Move to trash`

**Step 2**. I chose/click `Open with other application` from the above menu and a new popup menu opens up with different options like:

`Document Viewer`

`Google Chrome`

`Text Editor`

`Sublime Text`

`Okular`

**Step 3**. I chose `Okular` from the above menu and the pdf opens up using Okular.

What i want is that these 3 manual steps should be encapsulated in  keyboard shortcut like Ctrl + O + P

Is this possible in Ubuntu 18.04 ?

PS:
I am using nautilus-folder-handler.desktop on Ubuntu 18.04

**Summary**

I want to be able to select any arbitrary pdf by single left click and then press a custom shortcut key that will open that selected pdf using a particular application such as okular.

I noticed that there is options like Ctrl+C for copying Ctrl+X for moving, Ctrl+I for checking the properties of a file just by a single left click and then pressing the corresponding shortcut. I want to do exactly this. That is the user left clicks one time on a file and then press the shortcut which will open the file with a given application.

Comment: What is the file manager?

Comment: Yes, depending on the desktop environment and the file manager you use.

Comment: I am using `nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`

Comment: On right click, you could of course simply use a nautilus script.

Comment: Aaargh, Jason, I forgot the time interval to prevent the virtual keypress  (Ctrl-c) to interfere with the "real" one. Fixed, please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two step process.

**Step 1**
This is exactly the same as answered by @Jacob Vlijm. That is

1. Create (if necessary) the directory `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
2. Create a file with executable permission and name it whatever you like. For example, create a file named `openwithokular` and put the following content inside it:

```
#!/bin/bash
okular "$1"
```

The result of step 1 is that if you right click on any file now then a script menu option will appear which will contain the option `openwithokular` and when you click on the `openwithokular` option the file will open with okular.

**Step 2**

1. Create the file(if required) `~/.config/nautilus/scripts-accels`
2. Add the following content inside it and save it:

```
F4 openwithokular
```

**Note:** Make sure to restart your pc otherwise it won't work.

The result of step 2 is that now there will be a keyboard shortcut associated with the menu option `openwithokular` inside the `scripts` menu option obtained from step 1. And this is what we wanted. Now you can just left-click on any file and press the shortcut you have set and the file will open with okular(or any app that you have set). This method is tested to work on Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Just a guess, are you Jason? The answer was accepted before time passed to even try the answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. A shortcut

You can use a selected file as argument to run a script (from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/920833/72216)):

*Setup*

- run `sudo apt install python3-pyperclip xdotool` to install dependencies.
- Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `open_with_okular`, and *make it executable*.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import time

time.sleep(1)
subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+c"])
subject = pyperclip.paste()
subprocess.Popen(["okular", subject])
```

- Create a shortcut to run the script. It will copy the (path + name of) the file, feed it to the script as argument.

#### 2. Using nautilus scripts

Not literally what you are asking, but the easiest and cleanest is to use a nautilus script.

Since you are using nautilus, you can add a custom action:

- Create (if necessary) the directory `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
- Create a tiny script in the directory:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  okular "$1"
  ```

  call it `open with okular` or something, and *make it executable.*

Now opening the file is directly possible from rightclick -> Open with Okular. 
The file will be passed as the argument to the script.

Comment: Your 2nd method i have tried and it works. But it has the problem that i still have to right click and then there is a option called "scripts" where "open with okular" is listed. I don't want to go through these choices manually so many times. I noticed that there is options like Ctrl+C for copying Ctrl+X for moving, Ctrl+I for checking the properties of a file just by a single left click and then pressing the corresponding shortcut. I want to do exactly this. That is the user left clicks one time on a file and then press the shortcut which will open the file with a given application.

Comment: In your 2nd method will it be possible to create a shortcut for the newly created "open with okular" option that appears when i right click on the file. I think that will solve the issue.

Comment: @Jason Liam it should work ad it is, but I am not at home. Can you open a terminal, type 'sleep 4 && /path/to/open_with_okular' then return and immediately select the pdf file?

Comment: The option will be under a Scripts item in your right-click menu. Name script as "Open with _Ocular": o then becomes menu hotkey. Then script is easily accessible by keyboard: Shift+10 s  You can also assign single hotkeys to nautilus scripts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/696901#696901 Note that python option that uses xdotool will not work on Wayland

Answer (score 0):

Settings>Devices>Keyboard 
Then locate custom shortcuts and set your desired shortcut ....
The command field should be

```
okular <path-to-your-pdf>/name-of-file.pdf
```

For example, if your pdf file is "notes.pdf" in Downloads, then the command would be

```
okular ~/Downloads/notes.pdf
```

Hope it helps !

P.S.: Don't hesitate to ask any doubts if necessary

Comment: This is very close to what i want but not what i asked. I want to be able to select any arbitrary pdf by single left click and then press a custom shortcut key that will open that selected pdf using a particular application such as okular.

Comment: I got what you want but i'm afraid if that's even possible